# Populate second select list based on first select list value

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to do a nested select list which is not working The values of the second select list dont get populated. Here is my code. I populate the first select and based on its value getter.php is called dynamically to populate the second select box (which is not working)

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="rg">Region</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select id="region" name="region">
        <option value="">Select Region</option>
        <option value="AR">Ashanti</option>
        <option value="BRONG+AHAFO">Brong Ahafo</option>
        <option value="CENTRAL">Central</option>
        <option value="EASTERN">Eastern</option>
        <option value="GREATER+ACCRA">Greater Accra</option>
        <option value="NORTHERN">Northern</option>
        <option value="UPPER+EAST">Upper East</option>
        <option value="UPPER+WEST">Upper West</option>
        <option value="VOLTA">Volta</option>
        <option value="WESTERN">Western</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3"><label for="tw">Town</label></div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <select id="town" name="town">
        <option value="">Select Town</option>

    </select>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#region").change(function() {
        $("#town").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#region").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is getter.php

```
<?php
include "../areashoppers/includes/cs_functions.php";
$sql = "SELECT distinct town FROM oic_areas_full WHERE region = '".$choice."' ORDER BY town ASC";
$st = $sc_conn->query($sql);
while ($r = $st->fetch()) {
    echo "<option>" . $r['town'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

This is what shows in the error log

> [02-Aug-2016 18:39:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: choice in /home/areashoppers/public_html/nylb/getter.php on line 3
>
> [02-Aug-2016 18:39:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in /home/areashoppers/public_html/nylb/getter.php on line 5

$sc_conn is my DSN defined in cs_functions

Comment: the error is obvious; where do you assign a value for `$choice`? Once you fix that, the second error should disappear and magic may happen.

Comment: Sorry but i'm new to javascript. How to i assign it to getter.php

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should be aware of the security risks associated with the structure you're using.  `$_GET` variables and concatenating variables into a SQL string are openings for malicious attacks.

Comment: I will do urlencode($_GET['choice']) to encode special characters

Comment: @user3449007 - that's not enough.  Please read up on SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to get the choice from the url by GET method.

```
<?php
include "../areashoppers/includes/cs_functions.php";
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$sql = "SELECT distinct town FROM oic_areas_full WHERE region='$choice' ORDER BY town ASC";
$st = $sc_conn->query($sql);
while ($r = $st->fetch()) {
  echo "<option>" . $r['town'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Look again, there is a wopping error in here that was not in the original question

Comment: Thats got it, _DV removed_

Comment: Thanks for the info @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2):

`Undefined variable: choice` is most likely causing the second error as well, since the query will fail if `$choice` is not defined.

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
```

at the beginning of the PHP script should clear up the error.

Including a variable in the query string like `getter.php?choice=something` does not automatically create a `$choice` variable, but it *does* store the value in `$_GET['choice']`.

If you want to safely use the `$choice` variable in your query, don't worry about escaping it, just use a prepared statement. Assuming `$sc_conn` is a working PDO connection, that would be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct town FROM oic_areas_full WHERE region=? ORDER BY town ASC";
$st = $sc_conn->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([$choice]);
```

Comment: I will do urlencode($_GET['choice']) to encode special characters

Comment: @user3449007 No dont do that $_GET and $_POST have already had a `urldecode()` done on all there contents by PHP

Comment: That is not the right place to use `urlencode`.

Comment: $choice = $_GET['choice']; was the missing part. Thanks