# auto generate drop down options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I think I can use this method but don't know what to do, I have 2 drop down boxes
one is gadget and one is brand, for example if my gadget drop down is empty, then my brand drop down should be empty as well, if I select computer in the gadget drop down, the brand should should drop down should generate a brand of computer brand (example: acer, asus, hp,) then if I pick cellphones it should generate other brand, example (LG, Samsung, Xiaomi, Huawei) something like that, the brand is in a database table and also the gadget also have a database table. Sorry about my English, not my primary language

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a code-writing service. Add your code and tell us where the issue is.

Comment: Here is a tutorial for your reference. Try some code, when you get stuck then ask questions. https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate second select list based on first select list value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728496/populate-second-select-list-based-on-first-select-list-value) (even though that question had an unrelated error in it)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, using javascript. Here's an example:

Javascript

```
var gadgetList = ['Cellphone', 'Tablet', 'Kindle'];
select = document.getElementById('gadgets');

for(gadget in gadgetList) {
    select.add(new Option(gadgetList[gadget]));
};
```

HTML

```
<select id="gadgets"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Repl. It loads data from JSON for two dropdown combos. Gadgets and Devices, Devices is loaded dependant on Gadgets.

https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/UprightIllegalMainframe